# Docker as provider for Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, salt-stack

I am using Saltstack/Shell to provision a vagrant machine, but now I would like to add Docker as a provider. I had a timeout problem, so I modified the timeout value. Now it seems that the machine is never going to work : I 've been waiting and nothing happens !

This is my Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define :nodejs do |nodejs|
    #nodejs.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    nodejs.vm.hostname = "nodejs"
    nodejs.ssh.pty = true

    nodejs.vm.boot_timeout = 50000

    nodejs.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8001
    nodejs.vm.network  "forwarded_port", guest: 3600, host: 8002
    nodejs.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.10"

    nodejs.vm.synced_folder "salt/roots/", "/srv/salt/"
    nodejs.vm.synced_folder "salt/minion.d/", "/etc/salt/minion.d/"
    nodejs.vm.synced_folder "salt/formulas/", "/srv/formulas/"

    nodejs.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.gui = true
    end


    nodejs.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
      salt.verbose = true
      salt.minion_config = "salt/minion.yml"
      salt.run_highstate = true
      salt.colorize = true
      salt.log_level = 'all'
      salt.always_install = true
      salt.colorize = true
      salt.bootstrap_options = '-F -c /tmp/ -P'
    end

    nodejs.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
    end

    nodejs.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap/nodejs_bootstrap.sh"


    nodejs.ssh.username = 'docker'
    nodejs.ssh.password = 'tcuser'


    nodejs.vm.provider :docker do |docker|
      docker.force_host_vm = true
      docker.has_ssh = true 
      docker.image = 'ubuntu'
      docker.remains_running = false
    end






  end
end
```

Without Docker everything was working fine until I added this part:

```
    nodejs.ssh.username = 'docker'
    nodejs.ssh.password = 'tcuser'


    nodejs.vm.provider :docker do |docker|
      docker.force_host_vm = true
      docker.has_ssh = true 
      docker.image = 'ubuntu'
      docker.remains_running = false
    end
```

The authentication is not working, I am obliged to type the password manually at each file sync ! (this is not the real problem )

This is the problem:

```
$ vagrant up nodejs --provider docker 

Bringing machine 'nodejs' up with 'docker' provider...
==> nodejs: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    nodejs: Docker host VM is already ready.
==> nodejs: Syncing folders to the host VM...
    nodejs: The machine you're rsyncing folders to is configured to use
    nodejs: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script rsync to automatically
    nodejs: enter this password, so you'll likely be prompted for a password
    nodejs: shortly.
    nodejs: 
    nodejs: If you don't want to have to do this, please enable automatic
    nodejs: key insertion using `config.ssh.insert_key`.
    nodejs: Rsyncing folder: /home/admin/vagrant_boxes/apiv2/salt/roots/ => /var/lib/docker/docker_1442333472_30184
docker@127.0.0.1's password: 
    nodejs: Rsyncing folder: /home/admin/vagrant_boxes/apiv2/salt/minion.d/ => /var/lib/docker/docker_1442333472_90011
docker@127.0.0.1's password: 
    nodejs: Rsyncing folder: /home/admin/vagrant_boxes/apiv2/salt/formulas/ => /var/lib/docker/docker_1442333472_52013
docker@127.0.0.1's password: 
    nodejs: Rsyncing folder: /home/admin/vagrant_boxes/apiv2/ => /var/lib/docker/docker_1442333472_20273
docker@127.0.0.1's password: 
==> nodejs: Warning: When using a remote Docker host, forwarded ports will NOT be
==> nodejs: immediately available on your machine. They will still be forwarded on
==> nodejs: the remote machine, however, so if you have a way to access the remote
==> nodejs: machine, then you should be able to access those ports there. This is
==> nodejs: not an error, it is only an informational message.
==> nodejs: Creating the container...
    nodejs:   Name: apiv2_nodejs_1442333483
    nodejs:  Image: ubuntu
    nodejs: Volume: /var/lib/docker/docker_1442333472_30184:/srv/salt
    nodejs: Volume: /var/lib/docker/docker_1442333472_90011:/etc/salt/minion.d
    nodejs: Volume: /var/lib/docker/docker_1442333472_52013:/srv/formulas
    nodejs: Volume: /var/lib/docker/docker_1442333472_20273:/vagrant
    nodejs:   Port: 8001:80
    nodejs:   Port: 8002:3600
    nodejs:   Port: 127.0.0.1:2222:22
    nodejs:  
    nodejs: Container created: 032bddad87adc9cb
==> nodejs: Starting container...
==> nodejs: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
```

It seems like I will wait for an eternity !

Any suggestions ?

**Update**:

This is the output of the debug:

```
 INFO ssh: SSH is ready!
DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute:  (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: echo -n "========== VAGRANT DOCKER BEGIN =========="; "docker" "ps" "-a" "-q" "--no-trunc" (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: echo -n "========== VAGRANT DOCKER BEGIN =========="; "docker" "ps" "-a" "-q" "--no-trunc" (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive..
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are doing this:

```
docker.has_ssh = true
```

But your docker image doesn't have sshd:

```
docker.image = 'ubuntu'
```

You can verify with something like this:

```
~$ docker run -ti ubuntu /bin/bash
user@4baf7c72d5a8:/# sshd
bash: sshd: command not found
user@4baf7c72d5a8:/#
```

You'll have to create one that has the sshd or use one that has been created with a Dockerfile that has the sshd installed.

Also once you see the problem above. Run:

```
docker ps
```

To make sure your container is running. If it's not then check your `/var/log/docker.log` file

Comment: in the Dockerfile I am installing OpenSSH:
` RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
 RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd `